# How can I add basic auth to an nginx configuration with rewrite

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication

I have the following nginx configuration I would like to add basic authentication to this configuration to this.

```
upstream phpfcgi {
        server 127.0.0.1:7777;
# server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; #for PHP-FPM running on UNIX socket
}
server{
  listen 80;
  server_name qu.abc.com;
  root /home/qu/website/current/web;
  location / {
# try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
          try_files $uri @rewriteapp;

  }

  location @rewriteapp {
  # rewrite all to app.php
          rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
  }

  location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
          fastcgi_pass phpfcgi;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
          include fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
  }

  error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

I have edit the location block to this

```
location / {
# try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
          auth_basic "Restricted";
          auth_basic_user_file /home/qu/website/current/web/.htpassword;
          try_files $uri @rewriteapp;

  }
```

But this one doesn't work with rewrite.
Could somebody help on this.

Comment: You can checkout wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule,  

 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-http-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: Hi @PravinMishra I have already try adapting from that. The issue that I get is the rewrite is done before the server check for basic_auth. SO I need the way to make this work by making it check for basic_auth first and then do the rewrite. Or there might be some alternatives way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would sound to me like you want to have basic auth enabled for the whole server, and not just a single `location`.  The way `location`s work, is that only one applies at a time, hence if you specify an auth policy in a single `location`, but it does a `rewrite` to some other `location`, then the other `location` will not be subject to the auth policy from the previous `location`

According to the documentation for [`auth_basic`](http://nginx.org/r/auth_basic), it seems like it's allowed to be used not just in the `location` context, but in `server` and `http`, too.

Therefore, if you want your whole `server` to require authentication, simply move all of your `auth_basic` directives up one level, from being in a single `location`, to being in a single `server`.

Comment: Thank you very much @cnst I have made it work. While doing what you suggest I have also notice that nginx doesn't follow the symbolic link address. So I have to use the real address that is pointed by symbolic link address also. I think might be the root cause of my problem in the first place.